# Check whether the function is smooth

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In my proof of Removable singularity, I encounter a problem about differentiability of an auxiliary function.

Here is my definition of the funciton.

> $f:= \begin{cases} u \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n -B_c \\ 0 \text{ in }
>  B_c \end{cases}$

Here $B_c$ is a closed ball center at $0$ with radius $0.5$ and $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n - B_c$. And $u$ obtains $0$ on $\partial B_c$.

And then I conclude, since $\Delta u = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n -B_c$ and $\Delta 0 = 0$ in $B_c$. Then $\Delta f = 0.$

However, I am concerning about whether by adding the extension, the differentiability of $f$ will not be preserved.

More general, consider a single value function $g$

> $g:= \begin{cases} v(x) & \text{ if } x \geq 0 \\ h(x) & \text{ if } x < 0 \end{cases}$

If $v(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}h(x)$ and $h''(x) = c$ and $v''(x) = c$ and both $h$ and $v$ are infinitely differentiable, will it imply $g$ is infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Consider $v(x)=x$ and $h(x)=-x$ in your second example.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How about the first?

Comment: The first example is also wrong. The fact that the second example is wrong shows that the "reasoning" lading to $\Delta f=0$ in the first example is not valid.

Comment: Or take $n=2$ and let $u(x)=\log|x|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you very much. Now I exactly know what was my issue.